Why does this bar chart have a bar with two yellows?

the chart has 2 yellows instead of a green then yellow.  .
Tried resorting the data, adding various transforms.
this is the data for the chart:
 ```
     "values": [
  {
    "category": "answer_time",
    "date": "2024-09-03",
    "dow": "Tuesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-03",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 6,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-03",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "category": "hold_time",
    "date": "2024-09-03",
    "dow": "Tuesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-03",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 5,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-03",
    "value": 98.02
  },
  {
    "category": "wait_time",
    "date": "2024-09-03",
    "dow": "Tuesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-03",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 4,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-03",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "system_abandon_time",
    "date": "2024-09-03",
    "dow": "Tuesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-03",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_abandon-equals=true",
    "order": 3,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-03",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "agent_abandon_wait_time",
    "date": "2024-09-03",
    "dow": "Tuesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-03",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-agent_abandon-equals=true",
    "order": 2,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-03",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "agent_abandon_time",
    "date": "2024-09-03",
    "dow": "Tuesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-03",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "Elixir.F",
    "order": 1,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-03T16:03:04.177902-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-03",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "answer_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 6,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": 23
  },
  {
    "category": "hold_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 5,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": 97.91
  },
  {
    "category": "wait_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 4,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "system_abandon_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_abandon-equals=true",
    "order": 3,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "agent_abandon_wait_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-agent_abandon-equals=true",
    "order": 2,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "agent_abandon_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "Elixir.F",
    "order": 1,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T07:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "hold_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 5,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": 18.93
  },
  {
    "category": "answer_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 6,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": 22.72
  },
  {
    "category": "wait_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_answer_time-greater=0",
    "order": 4,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "system_abandon_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-system_abandon-equals=true",
    "order": 3,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "agent_abandon_wait_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "/portal/call_logs?search-stamp-is=rd-current_month&search-agent_abandon-equals=true",
    "order": 2,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "category": "agent_abandon_time",
    "date": "2024-09-04",
    "dow": "Wednesday",
    "end_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "formatted": "09-04",
    "grouping": "day",
    "link": "Elixir.F",
    "order": 1,
    "start_datetime": "2024-09-04T19:00:00.000000-05:00",
    "ui_date": "2024-09-04",
    "value": null
  }
]
    ```

this is the spec:
  ```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "format": {"parse": {"ui_date": "date:'%Y-%m-%d'"}},
   "values": []
  },
  "description": "",
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "category",
          "legend": {
            "labelExpr": "replace(datum.value, /_/g, ' ')",
            "title": "Category"
          },
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "agent_abandon_time",
              "agent_abandon_wait_time",
              "system_abandon_time",
              "wait_time",
              "hold_time",
              "answer_time"
            ],
            "range": ["red", "orange", "chocolate", "gray", "gold", "limegreen"]
          },
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "href": {"field": "link", "type": "nominal"},
        "order": {
          "field": "value",
          "sort": "ascending",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "label", "title": "category", "type": "nominal"},
          {"field": "value", "title": "time", "type": "nominal"},
          {"field": "ui_date", "title": "date", "type": "temporal"},
          {"field": "dow", "title": "Day Of Week", "type": "nominal"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "axis": {
            "format": "%b %d",
            "labelAngle": -45,
            "labelFontSize": 12,
            "tickCount": "day",
            "tickOffset": 20,
            "title": "By Day"
          },
          "field": "start_datetime",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
          "axis": {"title": "time"},
          "field": "value",
          "stack": "zero",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": 15},
      "transform": [
        {"as": "label", "calculate": "replace(datum.category, /_/g, ' ')"},
        {"filter": "datum.value != null"}
      ],
      "width": 80
    }
  ],
  "title": "Call Metrics By Date [ P 99 ]"
}
    ```

here is a link to the chart if that helps:
my chart
Any help would be appreciated.

You have two separate "hold_time" data items on September 4 - one with a value of 18.93, and one with a value of 97.91.  The other non-null item on that day happens to lie between those two items, so they get separated into two distinct areas of the bar.

that is indeed the answer. would be glad to award...with a grouping of 'day' there needed to be one record per day from the query...
